# Loading basemodel with require.config

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have a basemodel that extends Backbone.Model and use it within all my models. I would like to include it in the require.config.paths so that within each module I can just do define(['underscore','backbone','basemodel'],function(...)). However, require is unable to load it.

I've checked all my paths and it works when I give a direct path to the file within my define function... models/mixins/basemodel

Is it not possible to include a module within paths?

Comment: What's not working? What are your errors? Are you getting 404's?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... if it's not working, have you set up your paths with require.config? At the minimum, you have to set the baseURL field:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl:'/js/',
    paths:{
        text:'lib/3rdparty/text'
    }
});
```

Then you can set up alias paths if you have long paths.

Comment: Yup - I already setup the baseUrl...the path to the module isn't incorrect. I am getting a load timeout for modules by require.js. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The only time I've gotten a load timeout is when require can't find files.

Comment: Yea I am not sure - there wasn't a 404 Error. Looks more like a script error. http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout - Will have to figure out what it is

Comment: forgot about the first one... if you have some bug in your code, then modules will not load... I take it though, that this is not the case.

Comment: Yea - I got stumped - just went with the long form models/mixins/basemodel until I can figure out the issue